# Changing img src with Jquery variable causes "unknown" as src result

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, variables

I am currently trying to change an omg src dynamically when there is an image set as highlight-img in the backend.

This is my html output: 
`<img width="560" height="746" src=(unknown) class="attachment-shop_catalog size-shop_catalog wp-post-image" alt="704-4_vorne" title="704-4_vorne" srcset="" sizes="(max-width: 767px) 89vw, (max-width: 1000px) 54vw, (max-width: 1071px) 543px, 580px">`

I am changing the img src with this jquery-snippet:

```
<?php
  $simple = get_field( 'highlight-foto' );
?> 

<script type="text/javascript">
  $("ul.products li.highlight_product a.woocommerce-LoopProduct-link img.attachment-shop_catalog").attr("src", '<?php echo $simple ?>');    
</script>
```

The Output in my dev-console for the script is correct:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("ul.products li.highlight_product a.woocommerce-LoopProduct-link img.attachment-shop_catalog").attr("src", 'https://menashion.de/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/704_highlight_image.jpg');     
</script>
```

So, as you see the variable is parsed correctly through but then is not correctly set in the target element. 
I know this is not the perfect way to integrate a php variable into jquery but I don´t understand, why this code is not working correctly?

Any tips?

Comment: Try wrapping the code in `(function($) { $(function(){ /* your code */})(jQuery);`

Comment: You mean after the <script>-Tag I insert the JS as complete function with your snippet? 
Or completely remove the script tag?

Comment: Javascript must be within a script tag or it won't exectute

Comment: Why can't you just output this PHP var as the image src at request time? Why is JS required for this?